# How to check my mail system?

Tags: windows-server-2003, email-server

I don't know If I am using one of those,  Sendmail, Exim, Qmail or some other system.

How do I check my mail system??

Comment: You need to indicate what system the MTA (mail system) is running on before anyone can help!

Comment: what is that? Can you give an example? smtp and pop3?

Comment: Which Operating System are you using?  If Linux, which distribution are you using?

Comment: My server is Windows Server 2003...

Comment: What do you use for an email client?  Outlook?  What version?  Or something else?

Comment: i am using windows mail 6...

Answer (score 4):

One good test is to telnet to port 25 of your mail-host and see what it tells you it is.

```
C:\> telnet mailhost.mycompany.com 25
Connecting To mailhost.mycompany.com
220 Mailhost.Mycompany.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 18 Jun 2009 21:15:06 -0700
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel
```

That would tell you your mailer is Exchange of some kind.

```
C:\> telnet mailhost.mycompany.com 25
Connecting To mailhost.mycompany.com
220 mailhost.mycompany.com  ESMTP Sendmail 8.11.7p3+Sun/8.11.7; Thu, 18 Jun 2009 21:17:26 -0700 (PDT)
QUIT
221 2.0.0 mailhost.mycompany.com 25 closing connection
```

That would tell you it's probably a sendmail of some kind. Just google the result string you get, it should be clear what it is.

**Edit:** If you're running it from either WinXP or the Windows 2003 server itself, telnet is found in C:\Windows\System32\telnet.exe. You can directly invoke it:

```
C:\> c:\windows\system32\telnet mailhost.mycompany.com 25
```

Comment: telnet is not recognized as internal or external command

Comment: @mcfadder_09: I'm assuming you're attempting this from Vista/2008/7. You need to install the Telnet client as it's not installed by default any more. Install it via Control Panel / Programs and Features / Turn Windows features on or off.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using as an email client?

I'd start by looking at message headers.  Open an email message you received from someone outside your company and look at Received: lines.  Send an email out to Gmail (for example) and look at it (with "Show Original" if you do use Gmail).  If your server is Exchange, there should be a line like: X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft Exchange V6.5

This isn't a sure thing, but there's often an indication of what mail server and MTA are involved.

Answer (score 0):

```
lsof -n | grep TCP | grep -i smtp
```

That should let you know what's got the port open.

Comment: is the command for linux users? Sory, my server is windows server 2003

Comment: whoops! Sorry! In that case, definitely use sysadmin1138's suggestion

Answer (score 0):

- Do you have physical access to this server?
- Can you login?
- Perhaps check the Start menu. The name of the mail server should be in there somewhere.
- Open the Services MMC window. You'll see it in there somewhere.

[Enable telnet on the Windows machine](http://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+install+telnet+on+windows) you're on.